# W10 factory reset, can’t get past rEFInd MM

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, reset, refind

Dell Inspiron 7559, I did a factory reset when I was having issues with my USB ports (fixed the issue) but now the rEFInd main menu just keeps going in a LOOP. I’ve tried every option under rEFInd and troubleshooting and factory restore. Everything brings me back to the rEFInd main menu. The safe mode instructions did not work, however, so I was unable to try that route.  Please help, I’ve tried online solutions for hours but I just want to get back to studying.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Reinstall Windows from ISO, keeping files: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: You can always try booting Windows directly, rEFInd can be useful in some scenarios, but NOT a requirement, far from it. So, as ALWAYS, UEFI settings > Boot menu, change the boot order to Windows bootloader manager and see what happens. If you need to update the question please [edit] accordingly.